# Load from string.xml resources files depending on gender in android

Tags: android, android-resources

I am working on application where themes and strings differs when user is male or female.
I could control colors depending on user gender but now i can't solve problem of strings
for example if user is a male, I will use

```
<string name="welcome">Welcome boy</string>
```

but if user female it will be

```
<string name="welcome">Welcome girl</string>
```

that is just for example.so how can i load the correct file from resources depending on gender value which is stored in variable  ??

Comment: You will have to add some logic to your activity or fragment to control this. Can you post the code for the activity or fragment which holds this?

Comment: "welcome" key is used in TextView in xml file

Answer (score 4):

There's no direct support for what you are looking for in the plaform, so you need to write the logic yourself and have two strings per entry (i.e. `welcome_m` for males and `welcome_f` for females). But you need to set it on your widgets from code depending of who is using your app.

Answer (score 2):

Define array for gender-specific expressions, for example:

```
<string-array name="welcome">
    <item>Welcome Boy</item>
    <item>Welcome Girl</item>
</string-array>
```

Define for yourself the `[0]` item is `male` and `[1]` is `female`

Answer (score 1):

You have to create 2 resources id for your string

```
<string name="welcome_boy">Welcome boy</string>

<string name="welcome_girl">Welcome girl</string>

if (isBoy())
    txtWelcome.setText(getResources().getString(R.id.welcome_boy));
else 
    txtWelcome.setText(getResources().getString(R.id.welcome_girl));
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: calling `getResources()` is pointless in context of Fragment or Activity

Comment: That is exactly what i DON'T want to do because i have maaaaaany strings so if i used "if else" style,it will be catastrophic